# How to create a .phy file for constructing a phylogenetic tree?

Tags: phylogenetics, python, phylogeny

I'm new here. I need to construct a phylogenetic tree from 16s Sequence data (merged 151 bp) and color the branches/nodes based on my experimental conditions. From [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/molecular-phylogenetics-using-bio-phylo-57ce27492ee9), it looks like I need a .phy file to make the tree. I want to use Biopython for this since I'm reasonably comfortable with python.

I have a csv file with the 16s sequences, the phylogenetic information, and the "name" of the sequence, and the experimental conditions. How can I make a .phy file from this?

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You simply use Biopython's SeqIO and AlignIO.
The documentation is https://biopython.org/wiki/AlignIO 
etc ...
The format you seek is phylip

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made a .phy file similar to the one here [link](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Tests/TreeConstruction/msa.phy#L1) (except that in mine, the length of the sequences is 253). I ensured that they all have the same length.  But when I ran  `al=AlignIO.read(open("for_tree_top10.phy"),"phylip")`, I got "ValueError: Sequences must all be the same length". I'm not sure why, because I explicitly checked that the sequences have the same length. Not sure what to do now :( Any thoughts?

Comment: Possibly it is not a programming issue but formating. There is no simple answer to trouble shoot this. Could you ask this as a separate question please? Obviously it is solvable but there's several possibilities and the Moderators will intervene if there are multiple questions within a thread

Comment: I have asked the question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60289336/biopython-gives-valueerror-sequences-must-all-be-the-same-length-even-though-se)

Comment: thanks answered it

Answer (score 1):

Python works great for tying everything together and file manipulations.  I find stepping out of Python, using system calls, best for alignment and tree building.  For example:

```
os.system("mafft --auto {} > {}" .format("unaligned_16s_seq_in_file.fasta", "alignment_out_file.fasta"))

os.system("raxml -f a -s {} -p 12345 -x 12345 -# 100 -m GTRCAT -n {}" .format("alignment_out_file.fasta", "tree_out_file.tre"))
```